# Function should return string or array

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a function that should return `String` or `Array`:

```
func someFunc(isList:Bool=false) -> AnyObject {
        if isList {
            var results:[AnyObject] = [11, "123", [], "22"]
            return results
        } else {
            var result = "123"
            return result
        }
    }
```

But compiler says:

> Return expression of type '[AnyObject]' does not conform to
>   'AnyObject'

Comment: why not just always return an array, but when your `isList` is false, return an array with only a string in it? Or why not just make the return variable optional and return `nil` in some cases, as it doesn't look like you're actually using the return string for anything.

Comment: yes it is a solution, but is it possible to return how i want ?

Comment: No, i can't return nil, because string can consist some values

Comment: @Arti Your code works fine for me, what's your environment ?

Comment: oh, yes, you are right, with any object it works, but:
```if isList {
            var results:[Kanna.XMLElement] = []
            for node in doc.xpath(xpath) {
                results.append(node)
            }
            return results
        } 
```
Return expression of type '[XMLElement]' does not conform to 'AnyObject'

Comment: oh, sorry guys. I solved issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results variable needs to be of type AnyObject instead of [AnyObject]. Basically, you need to cast the array of AnyObjects to a single AnyObject

```
func someFunc(isList:Bool=false) -> AnyObject {
    if isList {
        var results: AnyObject = [11, "123", [], "22"]
        return results
    } else {
        var result = "123"
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"AnyObject" is any *object*. [AnyObject] is an array, and arrays are values, not objects. And the other value you try to return is a string, which is also a value, not an object.

Your function should either return Any, or better yet an enum with two cases, one case [Any] and one case String.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it return Any?

```
func something(list: Bool = false) -> Any {
  if list {
    return [11, "123", [], "22"]
  } else {
    return "123"
  }
}

let result = something(true)
let result0 = something(false)
```

Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

The apple documentation suggests against using the **Any** protocol in this manner.

> **Note:** Use Any and AnyObject only when you explicitly need the behavior and capabilities they provide. It is always better to be specific about the types you expect to work with in your code.

[Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342)